# Add an image uploader in page builder

Tags: magento2.4.3, page-builder

I want to add new image extensions to allow extensions as shown below image.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/dCLIq9V.png]

This code is from the below path -
`/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/image.xml`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

> ui form

```
<field name="custom_feed">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">custom_feed</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload File Here : </item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="path/to/your_controller"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

> controller

```
public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId = 'custom_feed')
{
    $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
    $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
    
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'mp4']);
    // here you can add the extension and the allowed extension

    $result = $uploader->save($this->varDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
        );
    }
    $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
    $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
    $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
    $result['name'] = $result['file'];
    return $result;
}
```